# Visual Studio connection to MS Access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I can't connect to `.accdb` in Visual Studio 2017.

I've tried to install `AccessDatabaseEngine` and `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010/2016 Redistributable` too.

Other cases offer `2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components`, but it is impossible to download.

And last, I change `any/x86/x64` but it didn't help.

I always receive:

> The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things, but nothing to help me. By the end, I did:

- Delete `Visual Studio 17` and `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010/2016`
- Install [`Visual Studio 2019 Community`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community)
- Delete `Office x64` and install `Office x32`
- Install [`Access Database Engine 2016`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54920)

Now I can connect to `.accdb`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

On a 64bit OS;

1) If 32bit is installed "ACEOLEDB.DLL" should exists here :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

2) If 64bit is installed "ACEOLEDB.DLL" should exists here :

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

On a 32bit OS;

"ACEOLEDB.DLL" should exists here :

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

Also look at the latest driver : http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255[^]

Thanks!